# How can we find tan300° by using the compound angle formula with combination of tan(210+90)° as the value of tan 90 is undefined

Tags: trigonometry

PLEASE HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM AS I AM NOT ABLE TO FIND TAN300° BY USING THE COMBINATION OF TAN(210+90)° WITH COMPOUND ANGLE FORMULA

Comment: Why can't you just use reference angles?

Comment: @Frasier crane What did you mean?

Comment: Use standard thing like $\tan(300)=\tan(360-60)$.

Comment: You can use $\tan300^\circ=\tan(210^\circ+90^\circ)=-\cot210^\circ$.  But you end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $\tan(300^\circ)=\tan(360^\circ-60^\circ)=-\tan(60^\circ)=-\sqrt3$

Comment: I know the above method but I m asking why we cannot do it by the combination of tan(210+90)°

Answer (score 0):

Better to use $\tan(360^\circ-x)=-\tan x$

Again $$\tan(90^\circ+y)=\dfrac{\tan90^\circ+\tan y}{1-\tan90^\circ\tan y}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac{\tan y}{\tan90^\circ}}{\dfrac1{\tan90^\circ}-\tan y}=?$$

Comment: I think given the context of the question, $\tan(360^\circ - x)=-\tan x$ is the way to go. Your other formula will just complicate matters, presumably. +1 though.

Comment: Of course; $\tan90^\circ$ is undefined.

Comment: @AndrewChin, $$\cot90^\circ=?$$

Comment: @Mr pie I know the above method but I m asking why we cannot do it by the combination of tan(210+90)°

Comment: @SushantKumar because $\tan 90^\circ$ is undefined, since $\tan = \dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$ and you can't divide by $0$.

Comment: @AndrewChin, We can write $$\tan(x+y)=\cdots=\dfrac{1+\tan x\cot y}{\cot y-\tan x}$$  Now set $y=90^\circ$